# Python 2.7: CSV file is not writing in correct format

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, overwrite

I am trying to write a new csv file to store sorted scores. The scores are stored in a list called "scores_int" and have already been sorted.

```
# Should write a new csv file every time containing the sorted scores    
with open("srt_Scores.csv", "w") as sortfile:
    w = csv.writer(sortfile)
    w.writerow([scores_int])
```

The only problem that I am experiencing is that the sorted csv file is not being saved in the right format. What I want is to completely overwrite the old csv file and just replace all the values with the new list(inefficient I know, but it does the job I need it to.)

Currently the srt_Scores.csv file looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/2ad5428d27860d0b72d1554ca9f23a3a

What I want to do is to make my csv file write look like this:

https://gyazo.com/57cab4a01c93b477344156b141f09689

If anyone could help me it would be appreciated.

Comment: You are posting images to pictures of Microsoft Excel spreadsheets. These aren't csv's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `scores_int` is a list, you just need to replace `writerow` with `writerows` and make every value in this array a 1-element list:

```
w.writerows([[v] for v in scores_int])
```